# python-socketio not always emitting when tracking downloading of a file on a flask server

Tags: python, python-socketio

I'm using a flask server for RESTful web services and python-socketio to achieve bi-directional communication between the server and the client to keep track of download progress on the backend.

I take variable sio declared in the server.py file and pass it in as a parameter into a new object that will use it to emit to the client certain messages about it progress with downloading a file on the server.

```
sio = socketio.Server(async_mode='threading')
omics_env = None

@sio.on('init', namespace='/guardiome')
def init(sid, data):
    global omics_env

    if omics_env == None:
        omics_env = Environment(socket=sio)
        omics_env.conda.download_conda()
        omics_env.data_management.download_omics_data()
```

The issue is when the file is downloading in python server, it emits a message to the client every time it has written 1 percent of data to file. But it's doesn't always emit to the client every time it has downloaded/written 1 percent of the data to file.

It will usually report progress to 18% percent, hold off for a while, then report back 40%, skipping the emits between 18% and 40%.

Some might say it's internet probably lagging, but I did print statements in the download function on top of the emit function which shows that it's writing/downloading every 1 percent of the data.

I also have checked online for other resource. Some mentioned using eventlet and do something like this at the highlest level of code of the server.

```
import eventlet
evenlet.monkey_patch()
```

But that doesn't lead to the code emitting at all.

Others have mentioned using a message queue like redis, but I can't use redis and I plan on turning the whole python code into a binary executable for it to be completely portable on linux platform to communicate with a local client.

Here is my server.py

```
import socketio
import eventlet.wsgi

from environment import Environment

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, send_file
from flask_cors import CORS

omics_env = None

sio = socketio.Server(async_mode='threading')
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@sio.on('init', namespace='/guardiome')
def init(sid, data):
    global omics_env

    if omics_env == None:
        omics_env = Environment(socket=sio)
        omics_env.conda.download_conda()
        omics_env.data_management.download_omics_data()

    omics_env.logger.info('_is_ready()')

    sio.emit(
        event='init',
        data={'status': True, 'information': None},
        namespace='/guardiome')


try:
    # wrap Flask application with engineio's middleware
    app.wsgi_app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app.wsgi_app)
    # Launch the server with socket integration
    app.run(port=8008, debug=False, threaded=True)

finally:
    pass
    # LOGGER.info('Exiting ...')
```

Here is the download_w_progress function that i pass sio into as reporter parameter

```
def download_w_progress(url , path, reporter=None):

    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    # Helper lambda functions
    progress_report = lambda current, total: int((current/total)*100)
    raw_percent = lambda current, total: (current/total)*100

    # TODO(mak3): Write lambda function for reporting amount of file downloaded
    # in MB, KB, GB, or whatever

    with open(path, 'wb') as f:

        total_length = int(r.headers.get('content-length'))
        progress_count = 0
        chunk_size = 1024

        # Used to cut down on emit the same rounded percentage number
        previous_percent = -1

        # Read and write the file in chunks to its destination
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            progress_dict = {
                "percent": progress_report(progress_count, total_length)
            }

            if reporter != None:
                # Limit the number of emits sent to prevent
                # to socket from overworking
                if progress_dict["percent"] != previous_percent:
                    reporter.emit(event="environment", namespace="/guardiome", data=progress_dict)


            # TODO(mak3): Remove or uncomment in production
            if progress_dict["percent"] != previous_percent:
                print(progress_dict["percent"], end='\r')

            progress_count += chunk_size
            previous_percent = progress_dict["percent"]

            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
                f.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I missed this question when you posted it.

There are a couple of problems in your code. You are choosing the `async_mode='threading`. In general it is best to omit this argument and let the server choose the best async mode depending on the server that you are using. When you add eventlet, for example, the threading mode is not going to work, there is actually a specific async mode for eventlet.

So my recommendation would be to:

1. remove the `async_mode` argument in the `socketio.Server()` constructor
2. install eventlet in your virtual environment
3. replace the `app.run()` section in your script with code that starts the eventlet server, or given that you are using Flask, use the Flask-SocketIO extension, which already has this code built in.
4. add a `sio.sleep(0)` call inside the loop where you read your file. This will give eventlet a chance to keep all tasks running smoothly.